# How can I get the encoding of my system?

Tags: windows-xp, language, locale

Is there any command for command prompt through which I can know the default encoding of my system?

Comment: Does the command "chcp" work? That will show the code page currently set for CMD.

Answer (score 4):

Just head to the 'Control Panel' → 'Regional and Language Options' → 'Advanced' tab.

Or

[Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default) has a solution to get the encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page. You can use the following VB code:

```
'Declaration (FYI)
'Public Shared ReadOnly Property Default As Encoding


'Usage
Dim value As System.Text.Encoding
value = System.Text.Encoding.Default
System.Console.WriteLine(value.WebName) ' (e.g.)
```

There are also syntaxes for C#, C++ and JScript. Have a look at [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default) for more info.